# Update next-auth session object after updating user via patch request

Tags: reactjs, rest, next.js, next-auth

I have been searching all over the Internet for an answer but without any results.There were some hacks around this but once I tried them they did not work for me.

So since user logs in and session is created, how can I update that session object with new data after I update user via patch request on a API backend.

I tried various "hacks" around the web that worked for some, but not for me.
I want to update session object after calling patch and updating user data

Comment: I'm here stuck on the same problem. Hopefully this question gets some traction again with my comment.

Comment: Have you been able to find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

So i made an article about how to fix this at medium [How to Update User Session Data in NextAuth using the useSession() Hook](https://kcib.medium.com/how-to-update-user-session-data-in-nextauth-using-the-usesession-hook-9846d70ada06)

```
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/client';

export default function UserInfo() {
  const { data: session, update } = useSession();

  const handleUpdateUser = async () => {
    const newSession = {
      ...session,
      user: {
        ...session?.user,
        email: "someone@example.com"
      },
    };

    await update(newSession);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleUpdateUser}>
      Update User
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: why does this works on a aws staging but does not work on vercel production ?

Comment: I'm also having problems getting this working on vercel.

Comment: Do we have any equivalent solution for SvelteKitAuth?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was going in my `/api/pages/auth/[...nextAuth].ts` folder and adding a `trigger` and `session` to my `jwt` callback. The trigger can check for `'update'` and update your session.

```
  ...
 callbacks: {
 async jwt({ token, user, trigger, session, account }) {
  
  //this line of coded fixed the issue for me
  if (trigger === "update" && session) {
    return { ...token, ...session?.user };
  }
  //...other code

}, 
session: async ({session, token}){
//session logic for passing token data to session
 ...
}
```

On the client-side `update` is called with the response `data` from the server.

```
export const useThemeToggle = () => {
  const { data: session, update } = useSession();

  const togglePaletteMode = useCallback(
    async (id: string) => {
      const newTheme = session?.user?.theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/toggle-theme`, {
          method: "PATCH",
          body: JSON.stringify({ id: id, theme: newTheme }),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        });

        const data = await response.json();

        const updateUser = {
          ...session,
          user: {
            ...session?.user,
            theme: data.theme,
          },
        };

        await update(updateUser);

      } catch (err) {
        console.log("There was an error with updating theme.", err);
      }
    },
    [session]
  );

  return {
    togglePaletteMode,
  };
};
```